# Как присвоить значение импортированной переменной?

Tags: javascript

Экспортирую переменную из одного файла (1) в другой (2), пытаюсь присвоить ей значение (3), и вылезает вот такая ошибка (4). Как это исправить?

1. `export let token;`
2. `import { token } from '../../scripts/common.js';`
3. `token = data.payload;`
4. TypeError: Cannot set property token of # which has only a getter

Вот весь код common.js

```
// проверка подключения к интернету
export let onlineStatus = navigator.onLine;
window.addEventListener("online", () => {
  onlineStatus = true;
});
window.addEventListener("offline", () => {
  onlineStatus = false;
});

// создание элемента
export function createEl({ tag = 'div', ...other }) {
  checkData('tag', tag);
  const el = document.createElement(tag);
  const props = [];
  for (const prop in el) {
    props.push(prop);
  }
  // добавление свойств элементу
  Object.entries(other).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key === 'classList') {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach(elClass => {
          checkData(key, elClass);
          el.classList.add(elClass);
        })
      }
      else {
        checkData(key, value);
        el.classList.add(value);
      }
    }
    else if (key === 'parent') {
      checkData(key, value, 'object');
      value.append(el);
    }
    else {
      checkProp(key);
      // checkData(key, value);
      el[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return el;

  // функция проверки типа передаваемого значения
  function checkData(key, value, dataType = 'string') {
    if (typeof (value) === dataType) return true;
    throw new TypeError(`значение свойства ${key} должно иметь тип ${dataType}`);
  }

  // функция проверки наличия свойства у элемента
  function checkProp(key) {
    if (props.includes(key)) return;
    throw new Error(`у элемента ${tag} нет свойства ${key}`);
  }
}

export const BACKEND = 'http://localhost:3000';

export let token;
```

Comment: Хотите сказать, что в файле прям так и написано: `let token;` ?  то есть нет такого, что токен - это класс и вы экспортируете именно его?  .... покажите содержание `common.js`

Comment: Да, там так и написано, token это не класс

Comment: Начав искать с другого конца я выяснил, что нельзя изменять импортируемые переменные, как бы они не были объявлены :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А никак нельзя, оказалось что менять импортируемые переменные в JS невозможно